# AspectJ does not work on Spring @Controller methods

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I tryed to do aspectj-based security for controllers, but when i try to use my annotation - it's does not work. but when i try to annotate deeper service methods - all works perfectly.

Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Loggable
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Principal principal, HttpSession session) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            String email = authentication.getName();
            Account acc = accountService.findByEmail(email);
            session.setAttribute("user", acc);
        }
        return principal != null ? accountService.findByEmail(principal.getName()).getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("ROLE_ADMIN") ? "/home/adminSignedIn" : "home/homeSignedIn" : "home/homeNotSignedIn";
    }
```

Annotation

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
// @Documented
//@Documented
@Component
public @interface Loggable {

}
```

Aspect class

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Logger {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test");

    @Around("@annotation(com.proj.server.aspect.log.Loggable)")
    public Object traceMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        String methodName = signature.getDeclaringTypeName() + "#" + method.getName();
        logger.info("START : " + methodName);
        Object o = pjp.proceed();
        logger.info("END : " );
        return o;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.proj.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>version</version>
    <name>proj</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <ch.qos.logback-version>1.0.13</ch.qos.logback-version>
        <org.thymeleaf-version>2.1.3.RELEASE</org.thymeleaf-version>
        <org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3-version>2.1.1.RELEASE</org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3-version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-repository</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- View -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${org.thymeleaf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${org.thymeleaf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
            <version>${org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javax.validation (JSR-303) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>test-version</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>${systest.package}</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*$*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Test*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test-all</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.17</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/WebSuite*</include>

                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>${systest.package}</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*$*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*Test*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)

in appconfig.class

Comment: Probably your Spring AOP configuration is the problem. Please update your question and show the Spring config XML or config class with annotations. I am not a Spring user, but others might be able to help you. I know AspectJ syntax and your aspect looks okay even though the advice is a bit awkward with so much reflection being used. But that is not the problem here.

Comment: Hi kriegaex, do you have any idea about eh security, mvc context that can be set to fix this issue? I am having similar issue with loggers not coming for controller classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is problem with different contexts. i have @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) in appconfig.class . all get work after i add something like that in security and mvc contexts.

Comment: Hi @midikko, can you please give example of what you've added in security and mvc contexts? I am facing the similar issue with AspectJ logging.

Comment: @Dish maybe it is not sound professional, but just add that annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) on the web mvc config class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @annotation(com.proj.server.aspect.log.Loggable) as your pointcut expression use 
"@com.proj.server.aspect.log.Loggable * *(..)" give it a try it should work

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'pointcut name' at character position 1
@com.proj.server.aspect.log.Loggable * *(..)

Comment: it is @Around("execution(@com.proj.server.aspect.log.Loggable * *(..))") or spent some time on how to form a point cut expression, it is very easy :)

Comment: nothing printed. and annotation on non-controller service methods is still work.