# Spring MVC and AOP: @Pointcuts for @Controllers only works in Testing and not for Production

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-java-config, spring-aspects

I am working with Spring Framework 4.3.3 in a Web Environment:

I have two contexts:

- `RootApplicationContext`
- `ServletApplicationContext`

I know the `ServletApplicationContext` contains all the beans about the web side, for example `@Controller`. Furthermore `ServletApplicationContext` is able to access all the context or beans from the `RootApplicationContext` for example `@Service, @Repository` etc. Until here I am fine.

**Note** it applies for `@Configuration` classes too. (Infrastructure)

Therefore with the previous introduction we can think in the following way:

- `ServletApplicationContext` --> `RootApplicationContext`

Something important to take in consideration is that the inverse is **not** possible.

Therefore

- `RootApplicationContext` --> `ServletApplicationContext`

is **not** possible. It has sense and is Ok. Server side should not access the Web side

About AspectJ. I have the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopConfig {

}
```

Here one important point:

- This `AopConfig` is scanned by `RootApplicationContext`

  - I trust that `ServletApplicationContext` can refer that `@Configuration` through the access of `RootApplicationContext`

Ok, when I run my `@Test` methods.

When I execute a Test class from the server side I use

- `@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class} )`

  - Only `RootApplicationContext`

And AOP works fine. I can confirm through `AOP + logging` the following process:

- `@Service` -> `@Repository`

When I execute a Test class from the Web side I use:

- `@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, ServletApplicationContext.class})`

  - `RootApplicationContext` **and** `ServletApplicationContext`

And AOP works fine. I can confirm through `AOP + logging` the following process:

- `@Controller` -> `@Service` -> `@Repository`

Now for production I have:

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootApplicationContext.class};
    }

   @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ServletApplicationContext.class};
    }
```

But when I export the project for a `.war` file and through an URL/URI a `Controller` is executed the expected behaviour or process works fine. But about AOP through `AOP + logging` the following process happens:

- `@Service` -> `@Repository`

`@Controller` does not appear for the output. The expected flow process should be:

- `@Controller` -> `@Service` -> `@Repository`

So why works in Testing and not in production?

I already did a research and I have found these two posts:

- [Spring AOP Advice on Annotated Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310115/spring-aop-advice-on-annotated-controllers)
- [AspectJ does not work on Spring @Controller methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290247/aspectj-does-not-work-on-spring-controller-methods)

Practically they say that the `@Configuration` class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` should be scanned through `ServletApplicationContext` and not through `RootApplicationContext`

Even when it is true (according with new experiments), consider that Server side should be tested without a Web Environment.

For other `@Bean`s about infrastructure through `@Configuration` the relation already explained about `ServletApplicationContext --> RootApplicationContext` works how is expected. Just with AOP has this situation.

**Question 01**: So why this behaviour?

**Question 02**: How keep the `AopConfig` scanned by `RootApplicationContext` and get the expected behaviour for production?

**Note** if `AopConfig` is scanned by `ServletApplicationContext`. The following about testing is valid **and mandatory** for the server side `@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, AopConfig.class} )`. See the addition of `AopConfig.class` but I think `AopConfig` should be scanned by `RootApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that `@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, ServletApplicationContext.class})` in test environment and context inheritance in production is not the same things.
In test environment you include `RootApplicationContext` and `ServletApplicationContext` as parts of your test application context. In production inheritance is used instead of a simple inclusion, as you described in your question.

Seems that `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (which is `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in your case) from parent context not applied to child contexts. To make it work in production you must explicitly define `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in child context too.

In this case Spring context definition should be about as code below:

```
@Configuration
@Import(AopConfig.class)
public class RootApplicationContext {
    ...
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@Import(AopConfig.class)
public class ServletApplicationContext {
    ...
}
```

Or

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={AopConfig.Class, ...})
public class RootApplicationContext {
    ...
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={AopConfig.Class, ...})
public class ServletApplicationContext {
    ...
}
```

[Related Task](http://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14753)

Comment: Hello, do you mean `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` declared twice? It for both context? wondered if it has some performance impact. Apart, I remember an annotation about testing where applies `context inheritance`. Yes, it is `@ContextHierarchy`. I have confirmed the functionality of have two `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. I will check through a JIRA if is a bug or not... perhaps something special through a `@Configuration` would be added and works how should be expected.

Comment: Cool! interesting what Spring will say

Comment: For the moment I am scanning twice from `RootApplicationContext` and `ServletApplicationContext` the *unique* class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

Comment: Have you tried to use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in both contexts like I suggest? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310115/spring-aop-advice-on-annotated-controllers/35638595#35638595) answer confirms that `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` do not affects in child servlet context.

Comment: Yes, like I said, my class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is scanned twice, one for each `Application Context`

Comment: It works now... sorry by the confusion I forget to re run the app

Comment: Pls sure to indicate in your answer that the class annotated with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` must be scanned twice by `RootApplicationContext` and `ServletApplicationContext`. Share the JIRA link how reference. Here the Spring version should be take it in consideration for the future too.

Comment: Probably this is an offtopic, but I am not sure that `@ComponentScan` is better then `@Import` in that case. If you interested why then i can answer in separate question... :)

Comment: Using `@ComponentScan` you are able to scan components in two ways (even together): **one** by `basePackages` (`String[]` ie: `{"com.abc.a", "com.abc.b"}`) and **two** by `basePackageClasses` (`Class<?>[]` i.e: `{AbcConfig.class, XyzConfig.class, XServiceImpl.class}`) each class is used to detect its package and scan from there to all sub packages. Even ``@ComponentScan` has a filter to exclude some components to be scanned.  `@Import` only has `value`, it apply for `Class<?>[]`.

Comment: Is possible use `@Import` and it imports a class that has `@ComponentScan` and apply my approach. Normally I use `@Configuration` + `@ComponentScan`. `@Import` is not bad